# Dygraphs - Can't see Data points if my graph collides (merge) with X-axis

Tags: dygraphs

When I have a graph which collides or merge with X-axis, I am not able to see the data points on it when hovered.

Dygraphs Image:
[image]
Above Image shows two horizontal lines on graph, one at "-40" (blue) and other at "0" (light green). On mouse hover, only "-40" line shows points but not the "0" one.

Is it because the line at "0" is on boundary ?
Is there a way to tell Dygraphs to show data points even when the graph collides with x-axis ?

Comment: Are you explicitly setting a value range? Or telling dygraphs to include zero on the y-axis? You might try passing something like `valueRange: [-45, 5]` in the options to the `Dygraph` constructor.

Comment: @danvk  Thanks for your reply. I m not setting the value range in this scenario. Based on Response data coming from database, the Dygraph automatically scales and shows the graph. 

Interesting thing is, if I scale Y-axis with valueRange:[-45, 5], then I can see the Points on both lines of my graph.

Can we tell Dygraphs to include "0" on Y-axis ?

Answer (score 0):

I called updateOptions() method with valueRange : [-45, 5].
Now I can see points on both lines correctly.

Is there a way to tell Dygraph to include 0 on Y-axis?
So that I dont need to scale Y-axis again to view the line on boundary. Thanks much.

[Image showing two points correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUZuc.png)
[image: Image showing two points correctly]

Comment: @danvk  It does show 0 when the graph is in positive Y-axis. But not on negative Y-axis. Please suggest.

Comment: That may be a bug. Feel free to file one with a repro via dygraphs.com/fiddle. https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/new